# Extract only data with certain value

Tags: mysql

Sorry about the confusing title. Couldnt come up with better.

Well I have table messages with fields id, from, to, message

Lets say there are messages from John and Nate for Dave

so it would look like that

```
id|from|to|message
1|John|Dave|Hey    
2|Nate|Dave|Yooo    
3|John|Dave|Sup    
4|Nate|Dave|Waazza
```

Imagine there is more of them tho.

Ok I want to extract messages for Dave and I do it like that

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ˙to` = 'Dave' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Ok all fine but this shows messages from both **John** and **Nate**.

Is there a way I could extract messages only from either(one) of them? Like I would extract only messages from John.

I am aware of doing another WHERE statement but I am looking for solution where I know only for who are messages not from who

Comment: I have one table one why would I need 3?

Comment: But how do you decide from who you want message if there are 2?

Comment: Please post your expected result from this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the from, you could use a sub query for example:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
   WHERE `to` = 'Dave' AND 
         `from` = (SELECT `from` 
                     FROM messages 
                    WHERE `to` = 'Dave'
                    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Using MIN:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
   WHERE `to` = 'Dave' AND 
         `from` = (SELECT MIN(`from`)
                     FROM messages 
                    WHERE `to` = 'Dave'
                    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Using MAX:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
   WHERE `to` = 'Dave' AND 
         `from` = (SELECT MAX(`from`)
                     FROM messages 
                    WHERE `to` = 'Dave'
                    LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

On the sub query you could use `MAX` / `MIN` functions to get different from.

[**Live DEMO of all the above queries.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dc51/6)

**NOTE:** this is given you know the name of the 2 persons you want to find the messages.

You can use `AND` to get the data which matches names from `to` and `from`:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
   WHERE `to` = 'Dave' AND
         `from` = 'John' 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ca4/2/0)

Or you could use the below for all messages of both:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM messages 
   WHERE (`to` = 'Dave' AND
         `from` = 'John') OR
         (`to` = 'John' AND
         `from` = 'Dave')
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9d3a/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE `to` = 'Dave' 
AND `from` IN (SELECT MIN(`from`) FROM message WHERE `to` = 'Dave') ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49098/1/0)

Answer (score -2):

You're mixing ' (single quote) and ` (back tick) by the way.
[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

As to your question, you can easily add more requirements using `AND`.

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `to`='Dave' AND `from`='John' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Now it shows only messages from John!